# Define 2 switchable implementations of the same functions in NodeJS / Express

Tags: node.js, interface

I have a bunch of field to calculate, and I have 3 cases.

Fields are mostly the same, but there is some differences.

Also, calculation to obtain each field may depend on differents variable, so function may have different signature.

In other languages, I would define an interface, use constructors using interface instead of concrete class and use dependency injection.

In nodeJS, I'm a newbie, and I saw there is no such thing that interfaces.

To take a concrete example, I must calculate

I have 2 case:

- case `sup36 === true`

  ```
  fixedRouting = (CG + CC + CSF * subscribedPower) / 12
  ```
- case `sup36 === false`

  ```
  fixedRouting = (CG + CC) / 12 + subscribedPower * billedCSFCoef * numDayInPeriod / 100
  ```

Right now, I add a parameter:

```
getFixedRouting(isSup36, CG, CC, subscribedPower, billedCSFCoef, numDayInPeriod) {
        if isSup{
            return (CG + CC + CSF * subscribedPower) / 12
        }else{
            return (CG + CC) / 12 + subscribedPower * billedCSFCoef * numDayInPeriod / 100
        }
    },
```

Problem is I will have more than 2 cases, and I will have to code more cases in the future. This way of coding will also increase the complexity of my code.

How should I do to be able to have 2 switchable implementations of `getFixedRouting(...)` ?

Comment: can you show some code that you've tried? In Javascript you have just one instance of a function but inside you can have it behave differently based on the parameters if you want.

Comment: I added the code in the question. Right now, I add a param, and have a if / else in the function, but it is not a very clean approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have different functions for the different cases like this:

```
function getFixedRoutingSup36(CG, CC, subscribedPower) {
  return (CG + CC + CSF * subscribedPower) / 12;
}
function getFixedRoutingNonSup36(CG, CC, subscribedPower, billedCSFCoef, numDayInPeriod) {
  return (CG + CC) / 12 + subscribedPower * billedCSFCoef * numDayInPeriod / 100;
}
```

This can be helpful if the parameters sent to each differ greatly (for example above the sup36 case does not need or use `billedCSFCoef` or `numDayInPeriod`).

If you like having one entry point for all of this you can still have the functions split above like that but have this one entry point that you tell people to use:

```
function getFixedRouting(dataType, CG, CC, subscribedPower, billedCSFCoef, numDayInPeriod) {
  switch (dataType) {
    case 1:
      return getFixedRoutingSup36(CG, CC, subscribedPower);
    case 2:
      return getFixedRoutingNonSup36(CG, CC, subscribedPower, billedCSFCoef, numDayInPeriod);
    case 3:
      return someOtherFunction();
  }
}
```

The drawback here is that if your variety of cases take a different set of parameters it can get ugly.

Another variant is to pass the parameters as a Javascript Object so the contents can vary:

```
function getFixedRouting(data) {
  switch (data.type) {
    case 1:
      return getFixedRoutingSup36(data.CG, data.CC, data.subscribedPower);
    case 2:
      return getFixedRoutingNonSup36(data.CG, data.CC, data.subscribedPower, data.billedCSFCoef, data.numDayInPeriod);
    case 3:
      return someOtherFunction();
  }
}
```